# Angular attribute directive get reference to other sibling attribute reference

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to define an attribute directive called pagingContext that should complement the functionality of angular material sort directive matSort.

My idea is to have an element defined like:

```
<table matSort [pagingContext]="pagingContext">
```

and a directive something like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matSort] [pagingContext]'
})
export class MatSortPagingContextDirective {    
  constructor(private sort: MatSort) { }
}
```

The problem I have is that the above example returns an error saying

> No provider found for MatSort

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to achieve this reference to the sibling MatSort directive?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Are you importing the module that exports the `matSort` directive?

Comment: Your code is work, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7v5eq?file=app/sort-overview-example.ts

Comment: Thanks guys, you are correct, I was missing the sort module import, my bad :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module, where your `MatSortPagingContextDirective` is declared needs to import the `MatSortModule`:

```
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
```

Also, your selector has a space in between the attributes that I think you may want to have removed.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy, my bad, I just realized that in fact I was missing the MatSort import, now it's working.